# Class paginator does not exist - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, pagination

I tried to use Capsule to create my own mysql database connection. I got a error message from Laravel:

**Class paginator does not exist**

Then I added a line of code:

```
$capsule->getContainer()->bind('paginator', 'Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator');
```

Another error message was showed up:

**Target [Illuminate\View\ViewFinderInterface] is not instantiable.**

Here is the constructor:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;

public function __construct($params){

    $capsule = new Capsule;
    $params = array_merge(static::$baseParams, $params);
    $capsule->addConnection($params);
    //$capsule->getContainer()->bind('paginator', 'Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator');
    $this->db = $capsule->getConnection();
}
```

ps:

```
$this->db->table('table_name')->get() work!
$this->db->table('table_name')->paginate(4) doesn't work!
```

How to fix this? Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same error message by running  Eloquent outside of Laravel. Maybe my researches how to fix it will be interesting to someone.

**Paginator** depends on 3 modules: **Request**, **View** and **Translator**. First and last modules are pretty simple to initialize, but **View** require an additional settings. So we need to initialize Paginator class and dependencies manually.

View class is most difficult to start, but we may use [this tiny package](https://github.com/PhiloNL/Laravel-Blade) to initialize it as standalone component. Just  add `"philo/laravel-blade": "2.*"` to the *composer.json* file

Then replace your *$capsule->getContainer()->....* to

```
    self::$capsule->getContainer()->bind('paginator', function() {
        // View initialization
        $views = __DIR__ . '/views';
        $cache = __DIR__ . '/cache';
        $blade = new \Philo\Blade\Blade($views, $cache);

        return new \Illuminate\Pagination\Factory(
            // Initialize and setup Request
            \Illuminate\Http\Request::createFromGlobals(),
            // Get ViewFactory instance
            $blade->view(),
            // Initialize Translator
            new \Symfony\Component\Translation\Translator('en')
        );
    });
```

Now you may use the **paginate** method. Just 2 tricks more. Maybe you will need to set a base url:

```
$collection->setBaseUrl('http://example.com');
```

and use `json_encode($collection->toArray())` if you need convert collection to json format

Read more about [the magic of dependencies here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/ioc)